# Why is the following assignment removing the "width and height" properties?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an array of objects:

```
elements: [
    {
      id: '1',
      dataX: 0,
      dataY: 0
    },
    {
      id: '2',
      dataX: 189,
      dataY: 189
    }
  ]
```

They are used in the template like this:

```
// This is inside a repeat loop:
<a class="btn"
  id="{{ id }}"
  data-x="{{ dataX }}"
  data-y="{{ dataY }}"
  style="transform: translate({{ dataX }}px, {{ dataY}}px);">
</a>
```

Final output:

```
<a class="btn" id="2" data-x="189" data-y="189" style="transform: translate(189px, 189px); width: 144px; height: 36px;"></a>
```

I have code that changes the value of `data-x` and `data-y` and the `transform` property, so the anchor tags can be dragged.

At the end of that function I have a few lines that change the array `elements` itself:

```
const target = event.target
const x = (parseFloat(target.getAttribute('data-x')) || 0) + event.dx
const y = (parseFloat(target.getAttribute('data-y')) || 0) + event.dy

// the code that makes the anchor tags move

// the code that modifies the array itself
 this.elements.map(item => {
   if (item.id === target.id) {
      item.dataX = x
      item.dataY = y
    }
 })
```

It works. However, the width and height properties are wiped out:

```
<a class="btn" id="2" data-x="189" data-y="189" style="transform: translate(189px, 189px);"></a>
```

Why is this and how to prevent it?

NOTE: `this.elements` is a reactive element. Meaning that if it data changes the element is re-rendered in the template.

**EDIT (full JavaScript code. I'm using [Interact.js](http://interactjs.io/)):**

```
 ready () {
    interact('#plane > *')
      .draggable({
        snap: {
          targets: [
            interact.createSnapGrid({ x: this.baseUnit, y: this.baseUnit })
          ],
          range: Infinity,
          relativePoints: [ { x: 0, y: 0 } ]
        },
        restrict: {
          restriction: 'parent',
          elementRect: { top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 1, right: 1 }
        },
        onmove: (event) => {
          const target = event.target
          const x = (parseFloat(target.getAttribute('data-x')) || 0) + event.dx
          const y = (parseFloat(target.getAttribute('data-y')) || 0) + event.dy

          // translate the element
          target.style.webkitTransform =
          target.style.transform =
            'translate(' + x + 'px, ' + y + 'px)'

          // update the positon attributes
          target.setAttribute('data-x', x)
          target.setAttribute('data-y', y)

          this.elements.map(item => {
            if (item.id === target.id) {
              console.log(item)
              item.dataX = x
              item.dataY = y
            }
          })
        }
      })
      .resizable({
        snap: {
          targets: [
            interact.createSnapGrid({ x: this.baseUnit, y: this.baseUnit })
          ],
          range: Infinity,
          relativePoints: [ { x: 0, y: 0 } ]
        },
        edges: { left: true, right: true, bottom: true, top: true },
        onmove: (event) => {
          const target = event.target
          let x = (parseFloat(target.getAttribute('data-x')) || 0)
          let y = (parseFloat(target.getAttribute('data-y')) || 0)

          // update the element's style
          target.style.width = event.rect.width + 'px'
          target.style.height = event.rect.height + 'px'

          // translate when resizing from top or left edges
          x += event.deltaRect.left
          y += event.deltaRect.top

          target.setAttribute('data-width', event.rect.width)
          target.setAttribute('data-height', event.rect.height)

          target.textContent = Math.round(event.rect.width) + '×' + Math.round(event.rect.height)
        }
      })
  },
```

Comment: Something is missing from the details here. Mapping an array won't affect any DOM elements directly. Create demo that replicates problem

Comment: Also that template has no width or height in style

Comment: As an aside (*not* related to the problem you're having) if you are not using the return value from .map() it's not the right choice. For your purposes .forEach() is more appropriate.

Comment: I added the full JavaScript code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my wild guess at what is happening in the face of some missing pieces...

You probably have some kind of binding setup so that when the array changes (as mutated by the `map` call) it re-renders the template; I'm assuming that.

The original template (pre `map` call) contains `width` and `height` values in the `style` attribute but is *not clear* where these come from. What *is* clear is that they are not included in your re-computation.

Therefore, my guess is they are being overridden by the `map` call because it re-writes the *entire* `style` attribute with ONLY the `transform`.

Add the `width` and `height` values back onto the dynamically rendered value for the `style` attribute and you'll be okay.

EDIT: With the full code posted basically everything I said is true except with the added flavor of *competing onmove events*. (I believe)

What I think is happening is your first *onmove* event is firing and setting the `width` and `height` and *then* the second one fires and overwrites the `style` with `transform`. Fixing this is a matter of changing  up the logic a bit so your event handlers are not fighting each other.

Comment: I added the full JavaScript code. Please see my **EDIT**. Okay, I'll try out your suggestion. Thanks.

Comment: the problematic part is `item.dataX = x` and `item.dataY = y`. If I remove this nothing is overridden. But no idea why only assigning data-x and data-y values overrides everything.

Comment: I think because it triggers the re-render and because of whatever data-binding magic is in play. I suspect that because of this: `"transform: translate({{ dataX }}px, {{ dataY}}px);">` I could be wrong though, not intimately familiar with interact.js

Comment: You were right. I solved this by doing `  item.dataWidth = event.rect.width item.dataHeight = event.rect.height` inside `resizable`.